# React Native - Put child components into parent according to 'key' leads error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Here I am creating a react-native project which have installed `react-navigation`.
I have switch on the StackNavigator for pages across the application. Below is what I would like to archive.

I would like to use StackNavigator without using the provided header. Therefore I create a component `<Header>` like below:

```
export default class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  detectKeyAndRender(item) {
    if (item.key === "left") {
      return <View style={leftContainerStyle}>{item}</View>;
    } else if (item.key === "middle") {
      return <View style={middleContainerStyle}>{item}</View>;
    } else if (item.key === "right") {
      return <View style={rightContainerStyle}>{item}</View>;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View key="header" style={headerContainerStyle}>
        { this.props.children.map((item) => ( this.detectKeyAndRender(item) )) }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Also for the common styles and container structure, I have created a component called `<BaseContainer>` like below:

```
import { getChildComponent } from 'helper.js';

export default class BaseContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView key="safe-area-view" style={safeAreaViewStyle}>

        { /* Please set the header from each page */ }
        { getChildComponent(this.props.children, "header") }

        <View style={outerContainerStyle}>
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={scrollViewStyle} alwaysBounceVertical={false}>

            { /* Page content goes in here */ }
            { getChildComponent(this.props.children, "content") }

          </ScrollView>
        </View>

      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

And also the `helper.js`:

```
export function getChildComponent(children, key) {
  return children.filter( (comp) => {
    return comp.key === key;
  });
}
```

Thus in other pages, I can call the header like below:

```
export default class FirstPage extends Component {
  render() {
    <BaseContainer>
      <Header key="header">
        <Text key="left">Left</Text>
        <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 20}} key="middle">First Page</Text>
        <Text key="right">Right</Text>
      </Header>
      <View key="content">
        <Text>This is first page.</Text>
      </View>
    </BaseContainer>
  }
}

export default class SecondPage extends Component {
  render() {
    <BaseContainer>
      <Header key="header">
        <Text key="left">Left</Text>
        <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 20}} key="middle">Second Page</Text>
        <Text key="right">Right</Text>
      </Header>
      <View key="content">
        <Text>This is second page.</Text>
      </View>
    </BaseContainer>
  }
}
```

This render method of `<Header>` will bring out an error but it's not fatal. The error is about the unique key:

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" props.
Check the render method of `Header`.
```

I know inside react native, every key should be unique (for performance issue).

Therefore I would like to ask is there any better method to put the specific child component into the header, or add the style according to a "key"? Appreciate for any help.

Please try to make the solution as simple as possible. Combine some common code together is what I would like to archive.

**NOTE: I don't want to use the custom header inside `react-navigation` because the position it put is not what I want.**

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get rid of the error would be to add a unique `key` to the `View` Components generated in `detectKeyAndRender` by adding a second parameter to it. So your function would be e.g. `detectKeyAndRender(item, key)`.

Inside of the function simply add that key parameter to every returned `View`: `<View key={key} ... />`

Then when you actually map over the children, pass the index to the function:

`{ this.props.children.map((item, i) => ( this.detectKeyAndRender(item, i) )) }`

Comment: Using `index` as 'key' won't be a good choice. Please take a look. [Index as a key is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Answer (score 0):

Unique keys should be given to each child element.

**Header**

```
export default class Header extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 }

 detectKeyAndRender(item) {
  /* you can use 'left,'middle' & 'right' as keys - they are different */
  let { key } = item;

  /* do validation on style hence you are not changing anything on view */
  /* 'Conditional Operator' is used to simplify if...else...if...else */
  let style =
    key === "left"
      ? leftContainerStyle
      : key === "middle"
        ? middleContainerStyle
        : key === "right"
          ? rightContainerStyle
          : middleContainerStyle /* default */;

  return (
    <View key={key} style={style}>
      {item}
    </View>
   );
  }

 render() {
  return (
    <View key="header" style={headerContainerStyle}>
      {this.props.children.map(item => this.detectKeyAndRender(item))}
    </View>
  );
 }
}
```